# Creating a Parent Array given a Binary Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, hashmap, binary-tree

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to efficiently create a parent array given a binary tree.

I'm thinking of traversing it recursively, the problem is I'm not sure how to write a recursive function correctly so it returns the array.

I can write the recursive function that returns nothing, which uses a HashMap to map children to their parents:

```
public void fillParentArray(Node root, HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm) {
        if(root == null) {
            return;
        }

        fillParentArray(root.left, hm);
        fillParentArray(root.right, hm);
        if(root.left != null) {
            hm.put(root.left.data, root.data);
        }
        if(root.right != null) {
            hm.put(root.right.data, root.data);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to write this function in a way that it returns the HashMap though. Is this a messy way of doing things? Am I simply referencing the hashmap with each call or is it copying into a new hashmap each time?